# aufs fs is being mounted before component parts

Tags: ubuntu, boot, fstab, aufs

I'm having issues at boot time. It fails to mount the aufs (and so suspends the boot asking if I want to continue... no good on a server)

I thought I had set up my `fstab` to mount the aufs AFTER the component parts:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcaageadf2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcaageadf1 /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcaageadf3 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/md0        /mnt/tank       ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime     0       2
/dev/md1        /mnt/sub        ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime     0       2
/dev/md2        /mnt/heli       ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime     0       2
none    /mnt/video      aufs    br:/mnt/ssd/video=rw:/mnt/sub/video=ro:/mnt/tank/video=ro:/mnt/heli/video=ro    0       4
```

But `dmesg` indicates otherwise:

```
[   24.419593] EXT4-fs (md0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   23.316121] aufs opt_add:736:mount[743]: lookup failed /mnt/sub/video (-2)
[   24.898982] EXT4-fs (md1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   25.291669] EXT4-fs (md2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Any suggestions?